# Python & Scrapy: Issue with Scrapy version

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04 x64**, I've followed the **Scrapy** docs to install the package using **pip**:

```
pip install scrapy
```

Then I followed the initialization of the example project and try to execute  the *example spider*:

```
scrapy crawl example
```

and I get this error:

```
2015-02-23 10:23:42+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: example)
2015-02-23 10:23:42+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 34, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 36, in configure
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 37, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 33, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 23, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 65, in walk_modules
    submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/alvaro/vagrantenvs/example/example/spiders/example_spider.py", line 3, in <module>
    class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'
```

I checked with `pip freeze | grep 'Scrapy'` to check the installed version of **Scrapy** and I got:

```
Scrapy==0.24.4
```

but as you can see in the traceback error:

```
2015-02-23 10:23:42+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: example)
```

1. I tried to uninstall and reinstall
2. I tried also to update pip, uninstall scrapy and reinstall
3. I tried to install it using **apt-get**

---

- Why If I installed the latest version *(0.24.4)* it seems it's executing 0.14.4 ?
- Is this issue related with Scrapy, Pip or both ?

## Edit:

Here it is the file example_spider.py:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

If I execute `scrapy version` as @aberna sugested I got:

```
Scrapy 0.14.4
```

Comment: Post the import statement that gives you a problem. That's `example_spider.py`, line 3 (see error)

Comment: what happen if you execute the command "scrapy version" ? What version of scrapy is used ?

Comment: @aberna it says 'Scrapy 0.14.4'... How can I upgrade ?? `pip install --upgrade` is being ignored

Comment: even  sudo pip install --upgrade Scrapy?

Comment: Another approach try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue back then and It was because the **Ubuntu** package was messing with the **pip** package.

When I installed Scrapy using **pip** and try to run it, **scrapy** says that the package was missing some dependencies and then I installed **Scrapy** using `apt-get` and there is where I screwed up with the package version.

I recommend you to remove both packages from **Ubuntu** and **Pip** and then reinstall only using pip:

```
apt-get remove --purge python-scrapy
pip uninstall scrapy
```

After those actions finished you can **install it again using pip** and then if you do `scrapy version` you should get as response the newest version, in your case it should be **0.24.4**.

## EDIT

You can read this in Scrapy Documentation:

> python-scrapy is a different package provided by official debian repositories, it’s very outdated and it isn’t supported by Scrapy team.

To install Scrapy in Ubuntu they say:

> 1. Import the GPG key used to sign Scrapy packages into APT keyring:
>
>    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 627220E7
> 2. Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list file using the
>      following command:
>
>    echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list
>
> 3.Update package lists and install the scrapy-0.24 package:
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24

[Check Here: Scrapy on Ubuntu](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thanks ! I had scrapy package installed, after uninstall it with apt and pip and reinstall with pip it works perfect !

Comment: An absolute savior! I was getting such crazy errors due to the version problems on my Ubuntu and this reply saved me big time. Cheers.