# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'

Tags: python, scrapy

I just started to learn scrapy. So I followed the [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). I just written the first spider mentioned in that site.

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Upon running this `scrapy crawl dmoz` command on project's root directory, it shows the below error.

```
2015-06-07 21:53:06+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-06-07 21:53:06+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 34, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 36, in configure
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 37, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 33, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 23, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 65, in walk_modules
    submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/avinash/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/dmoz_spider.py", line 3, in <module>
    class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'
```

Comment: There is a known problem with installing scrapy using apt-get on Debian: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28736998/191442

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using *old* Scrapy (0.14.4) with  the most latest documentation.

Solution: upgrade to the latest version of Scrapy or read [old docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/spiders.html), that suit currently installed version

Comment: how to find the scrapy version?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it usually outputs when you run `scrapy`. Your question already contains `2015-06-07 21:53:06+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: tutorial)`  ;-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj the most latest version is 0.24.6. 0.14 was released more than 3 years ago!

Comment: @AvinashRaj install it with pip

Comment: but i installed other modules with `sudo apt-get install ...`

Comment: @AvinashRaj make a virtual environment then and install scrapy inside the envronment with pip. Or use scrapy's repository. Installation instructions are available at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error message was little bit different

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'scrapy' has no attribute
> 'Spider' (most likely due to a circular import)

And it was due to the name of my script file (scrapy.py). Please make sure that you don't have another file called `scrapy.py` in the directory you are running because it will be imported before the real scrapy module.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo pip install scrapy`. If you get `Python.h missing` error, then install the python header files with `sudo apt-get install  python-dev` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631135/python-h-missing-from-ubuntu-12-04))

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try:

```
from scrapy import Spider
```

Just importing module isn't enough if you want to use it's classes

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name Spider`

Comment: Check `from scrapy import *`? (even though it's not pythonic)

Comment: Yours would only make difference if `scrapy.Spider` was a module, and not imported in the `scrapy` package.