# Python(Scrapy) unpredictable mistake with "import load_entry_point"

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have such problem, I did nothing with Python or Scrapy, but when I started today my computer I got such error. I have found many different posts and tried some tips and advices, unfortunately, they are do not work properly and I worry not to break something else.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: service-identity
```

Therefore, maybe someone had the same error. If yes, please, let me know how you solved it.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried many things and direct search was without real results, only [Python & Scrapy: Issue with Scrapy version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670554/python-scrapy-issue-with-scrapy-version) was helpful, I have deleted Scrapy and installed it again. Magic, but it works.

Comment: You can try to installing scrapy in a virtual environment and see if that works.

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error?

Comment: Yes, I have tried few first posts, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue back then and It was because the Ubuntu package was messing with the pip package.

I recommend you to remove both packages from Ubuntu and Pip and then reinstall.

First remove scrapy with all local config file  from ubuntu by following command :

> *apt-get remove --purge python-scrapy*
>
> *pip uninstall scrapy*

After these actions finished you can reinstall it using following commands.Now version should be 0.24.4.

1. Import the GPG key used to sign Scrapy packages into APT keyring:

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv
>   627220E7

2. Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list file using the following command:

> echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list

3.Update package lists and install the scrapy-0.24 package:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24

It should work :)