# Python Scrapy will not run showing pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: service-identity

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, pip

Scrapy will not run on my Ubuntu 14.04 giving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: service-identity
```

Timeline: I had Python 2.7.6 installed which came with Ubuntu 14.04. I upgraded to 2.7.9 which is currently my python -V. I started by downloaded scrapy from the website (scrapy.org) following their Ubuntu instructions, and I got the error code above when attempting to use scrapy. Then I went through every imaginable stackoverflow for pip being broken, scrapy being broken but no good.

pip upgrade did not work:
[pip broke. how to fix DistributionNotFound error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error)

This guy had almost the same error but no response:
[Python(Scrapy) unpredictable mistake with "import load_entry_point"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088452/pythonscrapy-unpredictable-mistake-with-import-load-entry-point)
He pointed to: [Python & Scrapy: Issue with Scrapy version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670554/python-scrapy-issue-with-scrapy-version)

I uninstalled all scrapy and reinstalled with pip (it was installing version Scrapy-1.0.3) and it initially failed but I upgraded some libraries (libffi & lxml) and the install worked with a sudo run. Same error remained when running scrappy.

Any chance anyone knows whats going on? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure you have installed the service identity package. you can install it by:

```
sudo pip install service-identity
```

Comment: I ran this and it said that all requirements were already satisfied. But after I tried running scrapy again it actually worked! I'm not sure if this command did anything but its working now. I don't know what happened between now and last night but maybe this or a reboot did it! I'm going to go ahead and give you the check!